# Tecla Ctrl pressiona ao mover janela de acesso remoto

Tags: delphi, keyup

Boa tarde.

Estou com o seguinte problema:
Tenho uma aplicação em que a tecla Ctrl ativa um evento da aplicação, e alguns usuários utilizam RDP(acesso remoto) para utilizar essa aplicação, o problema é que a tecla Ctrl é acionada toda vez que o usuário move a janela do RDP ou troca de aplicativo e volta ao RDP.

Por exemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = VK_CONTROL) then
    ShowMessage('Tecla Ctrl Pressionada');
end;
```

Consegui ver que a aplicação detecta a mensagem WM_KEYUP e trata, o que acaba por acionar o evento OnKeyUp com o parâmetro 17(Ctrl), simulando que a tecla Ctrl fosse pressionada.

Gostaria de saber se alguem tem alguma ideia se este comportamento é algum bug do Delphi/RDP e se tem alguma possível solução.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]